# Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child (Details)

Tags: android

Im trying to put scrolview without success..
this the error i get:
 Rendering Problems Exception raised during rendering: ScrollView can host only one direct child (Details)
im getting this when i replace the linearLayout to ScrolView
heny suggetion?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.jbt.mymovie.Edit_MovieScreen"
android:id="@+id/editScreenLinearLayout">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Movie Name"
        android:id="@+id/SubjectTV"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/movieNameImplement"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/MovieNameEditText" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Summery :"
    android:id="@+id/SummeryTV"

    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SummeryImplement"
    android:layout_weight="10064.12"
    android:text="@string/SummeryImplement" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/URLtextView"
        android:id="@+id/URLtv"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="15" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/UrlImplement"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:text="@string/UrlImplement" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ShowButton"
        android:id="@+id/ShowB"
        android:onClick="showButton"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="press show to get photo"
    android:id="@+id/ErrortextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OKbutton"
        android:id="@+id/OKbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:onClick="onClickaddMovie"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CancelButton"
        android:onClick="cancelButton"
        android:id="@+id/CancelButton"

        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: "im getting this when i replace the linearLayout to ScrolView" -- you have more than one `LinearLayout` in your code listing. Please edit your question and change the code listing to put the `ScrollView` in where it is causing problems for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Error is saying that you can have only one direct child in the scroll view but you are adding more then one view inside a scrollview
what you can do is

```
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
android:scrollbars="vertical" >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    **<!-- Add here which you want -->**

  </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

so your code will be like

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/editScreenLinearLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.jbt.mymovie.Edit_MovieScreen">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/SubjectTV"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="Movie Name"
            android:textSize="24dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/movieNameImplement"
            android:layout_width="0sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:text="@string/MovieNameEditText" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/SummeryTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Summery :"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"

        />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/SummeryImplement"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="10064.12"
        android:text="@string/SummeryImplement" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/URLtv"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="15"
            android:text="@string/URLtextView"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textSize="18dp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/UrlImplement"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            android:text="@string/UrlImplement" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/ShowB"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="20"
            android:onClick="showButton"
            android:text="@string/ShowButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ErrortextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="press show to get photo"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="100">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/OKbutton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="onClickaddMovie"
            android:text="@string/OKbutton" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/CancelButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"

            android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:onClick="cancelButton"
            android:text="@string/CancelButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

  </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is pretty much what it says - the ScrollView only can have one child. You have a TextView and a EditText in it. Try to wrap those two in a LinearLayout and the LinearLayout in a ScrollView.

A ScrollView is a FrameLayout, meaning you should place one child in it containing the entire contents to scroll
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html

Answer (score 0):

You can not put two saperate view inside a scroll view, you need to add all view inside one view. Use this code, or similar one.

```
<ScrollView
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
tools:context="com.example.jbt.mymovie.Edit_MovieScreen">

<LinearLayout      
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical"

android:id="@+id/editScreenLinearLayout">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Movie Name"
        android:id="@+id/SubjectTV"
        android:textSize="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/movieNameImplement"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:text="@string/MovieNameEditText" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Summery :"
    android:id="@+id/SummeryTV"

    />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/SummeryImplement"
    android:layout_weight="10064.12"
    android:text="@string/SummeryImplement" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="@string/URLtextView"
        android:id="@+id/URLtv"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:layout_weight="15" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/UrlImplement"
        android:layout_weight="60"
        android:text="@string/UrlImplement" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/ShowButton"
        android:id="@+id/ShowB"
        android:onClick="showButton"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="press show to get photo"
    android:id="@+id/ErrortextView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
     />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:weightSum="100"
    >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/OKbutton"
        android:id="@+id/OKbutton"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:onClick="onClickaddMovie"
        android:layout_weight="50" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/CancelButton"
        android:onClick="cancelButton"
        android:id="@+id/CancelButton"

        android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
        android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```